# Can I embed a UI for placement of signature fields with Adobe/EchoSign API?

Tags: echosign

The DocuSign API has a feature called "Embedded Sending", whereby you embed a DocuSign page in your app that allows the user to interactively place signature fields on the document to be signed, using a drag and drop interface.

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSending

I've been reading the EchoSign documentation and trying to determine if this is possible with their API. The Widget functionality seems to allow embedding signing but I'm not sure you can use it to do embedding sending.

Does EchoSign allow anything like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is easily achievable using AdobeSign REST APIs.

While creating the agreement using [POST/agreements](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#!/agreements/createAgreement) API you can specify some interactive options in the request body, here you can specify the "authoringRequested" parameter to true, on successful API call it will return an embeddable url
to a document authoring page, where you can place various fields (be it signature field, text field, drop box or any other AdobeSign supported fields) on your documents. Once done the user can then initiate the sending workflow by clicking the Send button on that page.

You can further customise this authoring view by passing other parameters to this interactiveOptions json of your POST /agreements request like -
 
 "noChrome" : "true"  to remove the to AdobeSign navigation bar
 "autoLoginUser" : "true" to relax the user from signing in
 "locale" : "fr_FR" the locale in which you want the page to be render

This should solve your use-case.

Comment: is this removed in version 6?